# Web front-end design for concurrent modification

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, locking

I am creating a web application which has a few management screens, where a user can go to edit records (for example, changing the contact details of a user). Access to these managements screens are controlled by roles, with multiple users possibly having access. The problem now arises of what to do if two users simultaneously try to edit the same record.

My problem is with the front-end, not with the back-end. What are some of the patterns I can use in order to design my pages so as to be both user-friendly and prevent concurrent modifications? The only two options I can think of are these:

- Pessimistic locking: Difficult in a web environment where I'd need to wait for the session to timeout before being able to release the lock in most cases.
- Optimistic locking: Not that good in terms of user-friendliness, as a user might fill in a large form only to be greeted with a "cannot save" message at the end.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Optimistic locking has nothing to do with being user-friendly or otherwise; it's down to the implementation.  The big question is what is the expected frequency of simultaneous edits on the same record?  If low, simple optimistic locking wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a timed reservation? This is a model used in many on-line booking systems.

An example based on trivial single table case (I hope that extending to more tables should be obvious) Add a column to the table called RESERVATION_TIME. All records are initially populated with a reservation time of "many years ago".

Use this in conjunction with optimistic locking. At the point you go into Edit mode you

- Make a reservation for the record you want

  UPDATE RESERVATION_TIME to NOW where KEY = id and RESERVATION_TIME more than 30 mins ago

This will only work if no one has already set the up update to recently. The idea is that we don't even allow the edit screen to be populated if some other user is already working. But we set that reservation to expire after 30 mins (or whatever) so that nothing is "locked" permenently. But note that we are not (in database terms) holding a pessimistic lock.

- Now retrieve the data (maybe inn the same tran as took the reservation)
- on write back check the optimistic predicate and clear the reservation back to a long time ago.

Now this mediates between two users of any applications that honour the reservation system. The optimistic lock mediates between all optimistic users of the system, so it's still possible for the user to be irritated, but assumig that out-of-band updates are rare then you should get acceptable usability.

Some other ideas:

1. Last save wins - for some data there's no point in locking. You were going to allow user Bill to change Alice's work anyway and vice-versa, so allow either to win.
2. Detect conflict and merge. Like the CVS source control system. Use an optimistic scheme and in the event of conflict present the intervening update and the proposed updat and ask the user to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but could you please elaborate on your reservation suggestion. I don't quite follow - do you mean I should use a reservation-like pessimistic locking, but also allow for optimistic locking if you don't have the exclusive lock?

Answer (score 2):

We implement a first-write-wins mechanism in similar situations (or Optimistic Locking)

**BACKEND:**

Create a timestamp field in the database (this is automatically updated in MSSQL on an  INSERT and UPDATE)

When you load the objects for editing, including a timestamp property, only allow saving in your stored procedures if the timestamp is the same else throw an error, handle this in your application indicating the record has changed and give them the opportunity to re-load the page. This works well on the web/disconnected environments.

**FRONT END**

The page needs to poll the database (using ajax) to detect a change. If there is a change prompt the user indicating the record has changed and option to reload/merge. On the page postback display labels or secondary form fields (readonly) with the new entered values on the right that can be copied, eg arrow button pointing left that copies the values back to the original form fields.

Comment: That's optimistic locking isn't it? And the re-load is the problem the questioner has - deeply bunfriendly if teh user just spent 10 mins filling in lots of detailed info into the UI. "TOO LATE WE ALREADY GOT ONE! Type it all again."

Comment: "Optimistic Locking" and good point :-) thanks. Answer Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that Optimistic Locking is not that user-friendly.

For the pessimistic locking, I think you can get over the problem:

- To release the lock more often, you could use a delai for the lock, in your database. After that delai expired, another user could break the lock. The first user would be notified of it. That needs to be clear from the beginning.
- You could also use a recurrent auto-refresh in the locking page. At each (ajax) request, you memorize the time. Therefore, if on the server, a lock is older than the refresh rate, it means the user is not on this page anymore. So even though the session didn't expire, you can clean the lock.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Optimistic Locking user friendly by retrieving the modified records and showing comparisons with the data they submitted.

You could take it one step further and implement an TortoiseSVN-like interface for editing conflicts (if there are any).

This may require a bit of UI effort, but it would result in a nice way of allowing concurrent edits.

You might want to check out the HTML/JS/CSS code used in [Rietveld](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/) as an example of how to create a [nice diff interface](http://codereview.appspot.com/114045/diff/2015/1063).